# How to disable horizontal scrolling in webView with swift?

Tags: swift, uiwebview, horizontal-scrolling

I have a simple `webView` like :

```
@IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = "https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_456"
    let requestURL = NSURL(string:url)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
```

when I load this request into webView it loads perfectly fine but when Its load completely It scroll horizontally like this when I scroll it from left side and right side:

[image]

[image]

I don't want to scroll it this way and I only want it to scroll vertically is there any way to do it in swift I search on Internet but only found solution for objective-c and I try this in swift but not working.

Please provide me any solution for this.

Answer (score 8):

**Update Swift 4**

Add both these methods into your UIViewController:

```
    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    self.webView.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x > 0){
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y)
    }
 }
```

---

in the viewDidLoad Method add these lines:

```
 webview.scrollView.delegate = self
 webview.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
```

Now this wld show an error at line `webview.scrollView.delegate = self` so make sure you add the UIScrollViewDelegate like this

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate{
```

And horizontal scrolling has stopped :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but its not working for me did you check with `URL` I have given into question?

Comment: did you figure out a solution? it didn't work for me either

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for answering so late but you can do this by setting the scrollable size to the WebView scrollview after data loading is finished by implementing UIWebViewDelegate method.

> func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView)

you can do it by doing so:

**SWIFT 4:**

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    let scrollableSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.size.width, height: webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)
    self.webView?.scrollView.contentSize = scrollableSize
}
```

**EDIT:**

The key thing here is setting the webView  scrollView width to your main view width this will prevent the horizontal scrolling.

PS: Don't forget to adopt the UIWebViewDelegate Protocol

```
class myViewController: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate
```

and set your webView Delegate in viewDidLoad

```
webView?.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

If you came here looking for a way to get it to not scroll at all (horizontally or vertically) like I did, here's an answer that works with WKWebView in Swift 5:

```
webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
```